# scrape web content with golang

Tags: html, go

I am a beginner in programming languages ​​and I am learning scrape. Is it possible to get data in comments like this?

```
<tbody id="the-list">
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right">1.</td>
    <td valign="top">BEKASI</td>
    <td valign="top">Tambun</td>
    <td valign="top">Selatan</td>
    <td valign="top">01.4.13.16.06.000013</td>
    <td valign="top">Jalan</td>
    <td valign="top">PERUM BEKASI GRIYA ASRI</td>
    <td valign="top">1.500 m<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">Kantor</td>
    <td valign="top">400 m<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">1998</td>            
    <td valign="top" align="center">> 200</td>

    <!--
    <td valign="top" align="center">-6.2245</td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">107.0827</td>
    -->

    <td valign="top" align="right">3</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">7</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">2</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">150</td>
    <td valign="top">08888123</td>
    <td valign="top">-</td>

</tr>
```

I hope the results can be like this

```
1.;BEKASI;Tambun;Selatan;01.4.13.16.06.000013;Jalan;PERUM BEKASI GRIYA ASRI;1.500 m;Kantor;400 m;1998;200;-6.2245;107.0827;3;7;2;150;08888123;-
```

Comment: In Go, you could use the `golang.org/x/net/html` parser for that, but as asked, this question is very broad. You're tagging three different languages, for starters.

Comment: golang doesnt have for scraping in its stdlib, you can use 3rd parties like gocolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[goquery](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) is great lib for parsing html content.

```
    html := `
      <table><tbody id="the-list">
         <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="right">1.</td>
            <td valign="top">BEKASI</td>
            <td valign="top">Tambun</td>
            <td valign="top">Selatan</td>
            <td valign="top">01.4.13.16.06.000013</td>
            <td valign="top">Jalan</td>
            <td valign="top">PERUM BEKASI GRIYA ASRI</td>
            <td valign="top">1.500 m<sup>2</sup></td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">Kantor</td>
            <td valign="top">400 m<sup>2</sup></td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">1998</td>            
            <td valign="top" align="center">> 200</td>

            <!--
            <td valign="top" align="center">-6.2245</td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">107.0827</td>
            -->

            <td valign="top" align="right">3</td>
            <td valign="top" align="right">7</td>
            <td valign="top" align="right">2</td>
            <td valign="top" align="right">150</td>
            <td valign="top">08888123</td>
            <td valign="top">-</td>

        </tr>
   </tbody></table>
`
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(html))
    sel := doc.Find("#the-list td")
    for i := range sel.Nodes{
        n := sel.Eq(i)
        fmt.Println(n.Text())
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it's working but I still can't get content inside comment :D 
   <!--
   <td valign="top" align="center">-6.2245</td>
   <td valign="top" align="center">107.0827</td>
   -->
thanks anyway

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no CSS selector for html comments. Trick is html = strings.Replace(html, "<!--", "", -1)